# PL SQL Retrieve maximum version number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below information and need to retrieve only the maximum version number

```
msg_id  version number
120 0
120 1
121 0
122 0

Result:
msg_id  version number
120 1
121 0
122 0
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select msg_id, max("version number")
from yourtable
group  by msg_id
```